# Is it possible to write back to data file in postman?

Tags: postman

While working with postman, `data.someVariable` returns data from within a csv file that can also be used as `{{someVariable}}` in uri/json.

This gives us the data for that variable from that row/iteration.

Is there a mechanism to write back to the data file by doing something like `postman.setData('responseCode') = responseCode`.

This would be really helpful to store response code in the data file and to record call wise details in same format as the input within csv.

Comment: Hello,
the data object being a dictionary, have you tried to update it then relaunch the request using setNextRequest ? I don't think this will modify the CSV file but, maybe, it could be taken into account on the next run ? I haven't tried it though ...

Comment: Postman allows reading of dictionary variables with . notation but doesn't allow overwriting like that. TO overwrite environment vars you have to use the setEnvironmentVariable function. I did not see any setDataVariable function.

Comment: Indeed. I tried to update the variable at the end of tests section and used setNextRequest(my req) hoping it would replay it with the updated global but this didn't work. The variable used the value set in the data file. Another thing to try, instead of using setNextRequest, would be to use the "Send a request" snippet available in the Tests part of your request (looks like pm.sendRequest  ...). But if it works it will not be very practical to repeat your request's call inside your request (and you'll have to execute it just once) ...

Comment: @ A.Joly: that is because data values override all other values of environment or global vars. If you have a data value X and an envt value X and a global X, then data vakue X will always replace anything that looks like {{X}} in that data iteration of that REST call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to write back to data file in postman as of now .

However, you can populate that in your environment file at run time using

`pm.environment.set("varname")`

keep varname in such a way that you understand this is the variable you wanted to write back into data file.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I figured out is

- to populate json objects in the environment with information about the data file name and structure/values of information to be added
- to create a separate web service (maybe in node.js) that exposes an http call to write to a file and takes in as parameter a json input as the one created in the environment as mentioned above and writes that to a file / original data file (or a copy of it) in the desired format
- to call the above mentioned web service call at the end of each run or desired rest call execution to generate step wise information/debug report